# Is it always possible for validation accuracy to be as high as training accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have a very small dataset (40 training examples, 10 validation examples, 120 classes) for which I'm getting very high accuracies with a very simple model in Keras (batchnorm, flatten, and dense layers only).

My training accuracy is 94-95% and validation accuracy is 76-78%. I know it's overfitting and I have tried a few things. The data is not images, so I cannot augment the data. I also cannot add data because it's a specific type. I'm using two dropout layers with 0.5 levels, and the architecture is very simple so I don't think I can reduce the architecture complexity. I can paste the model if anyone likes.

My question is: Is there ever a situation where validation accuracy cannot be as high as the training accuracy? Is there a limitation based on the size of the dataset? Or is it ALWAYS possible for validation accuracies to match training accuracies and the network just needs the right parameters?

Comment: You have 50 examples and 120 classes, how come? Can you please elaborate? Do you have multi label classification problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a situation in which validation accuracy cannot be as high as training accuracy. Any situation in which noise (as opposed to generalizable properties of the feature set) in the training set is more predictive of the target variable within the training set would produce this.

Consider a situation in which a random property of the training sample considered is perfectly predictive, but this is found not to be true of all other examples outside the sample. The predictive power in the training set would be perfect, but outside the training set, less than perfect. This phenomenon is broadly referred to as "overfitting".

For example, let's consider a case where you have a set of fruit data and you're trying to establish whether a given fruit is an orange or a tangerine. You have 4 features- the circumference of the fruit around the stem-medial axis, the height of the fruit across the stem, a numerical value of the hue of the fruit skin, and the first letter of the amateur baseball team whose home park is closest to the field the fruit was grown in. Let's imagine that by some baffling coincidence, the baseball team letter in the training set was perfectly predictive of whether the fruit would be a tangerine or orange.

We can imagine that this would not hold true across the country or the world, which would produce a situation where the training set accuracy would be perfect, but the validation set accuracy would not be able to approach that using the same methods.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Maybe noise is what is producing the discrepancy between training and validation accuracies. My data is all 2D matrices, on the order of 4000 rows and 21 columns.

Something I've been trying to determine that may belong in another question is if data of this kind can be augmented. When I look online, data augmentation seems to only be done with images.

Comment: You're very welcome- at stack overflow, answers are judged by upvoting- if you feel like the answer has value, please click the up-arrow next to it. If you feel like it has completely answered your question and is the best of the available answers, please click the check mark next to it to accept it as answer (though, please wait 24 hours or so at least to provide time for other answers to be provided which may be better).

Comment: If you think your data might require augmentation for a specific reason, there are many solutions to this type of problem, for example, if you have heavily unbalanced classes that you're trying to discriminate between,  SMOTE is one method of augmenting the under represented class. (https://www.jair.org/media/953/live-953-2037-jair.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I already upvoted your answer but it won't be visible because I'm at <15 reputation.

Comment: I actually have fully balanced classes. 40 training samples of 120 classes with 10 validation samples of each class. Will look into this method, thanks.

Comment: Aside from the occurrence of some obscure feature present in the training data that isn't in the validation causing the discrepancy, is it always theoretically possible for validation accuracy to be as high as the training accuracy? Asking because I'm confident the training data does not contain any outstanding features not present in the validation set.

Comment: I only intended the example as a metaphor- it could be any property of the dataset- the interaction between two features, a limited range of values of a single feature etc. Basically, absolutely anything that means the training sample isn't properly representative of the population.

Comment: I think the training set is representative of the population because of what the data represents. As I said earlier, the data is all matrices. The rows are different cells in heart tissue and the columns are all frames in a time series. The 120 classes are all different perturbations of the cells. The same cells are included in all training and validation samples, and all samples are the same time length. The classes are all balanced as well (40 of each class for training, 10 of each for validation). In this case, should it be possible for validation accuracy to match training accuracy?

Comment: One way of thinking about it is simply that there is a gap between them. In most cases, if you're regularizing (generalizing) the algorithm to better fit to out-of-sample data, you're going to sacrifice training accuracy for improved validation performance. I.e. correcting overfitting generally involves actually fitting the training set *worse* than the un-regularized algorithm would.

Comment: Overfitting implies that *the reason* the algorithm fits to the testing data comparatively poorly is that it fits to the training data *more than is justified for generalization*. If an algorithm is overfitting in this definition, validation performance *cannot* reach the level of the training performance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I suppose the only way to test whether validation accuracy can be increased is to hand-tweak the network's parameters and test it over and over again.

Comment: There are definitely parameter optimization strategies that don't require you to manually tweak the configuration. Here is one using the hyperopt package, for example: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1591 . Other options to consider are performing feature selection (i.e. removing some set of features that may be encouraging overfitting), incorporating the use of some regularization scheme (regulizers in keras: https://keras.io/regularizers/), or increasing or adding dropout to layers (https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout)